# Ember.js: Is it possible to have a component for each field in a model?

Tags: ember.js, components, each

So I thought I had this solved already as it worked with my prototype using just arrays, but now that I'm actually dealing with the model, I'm not sure if it will work.
If I create a property on my controller like so:

```
myAttributes: [{
  name: 'attr1',
  label: 'Attribute 1',
  value: null
}, {
  name: 'attr2',
  label: 'Attribute 2',
  value: 1
}]
```

then I can loop through `myAttributes` with `{{#each}}`, so while each object is essentially a field, that's different than the fields on a single model, which only have a value, so I can't do `{{#each model as |rec|}}` when there's only one record.

In a nutshell, I want to have a button group to set the value for each field in my model, like so:
[image]

I have around 60 of these fields so that's why I wanted to use `{{#each}}` and my component for each field, but of course `each` goes over records in the model, not fields in a record.

Is this impossible to do? Do I just have to bite the bullet and write out the markup for each field like I would do if I had only a few fields?

**Update:** Even if I could loop through the fields on a single record (maybe with `{{#each model.@each as |field|}}`?), for this case what I also need to do is break out the fields into sections in the UI, so for example loop through fields 1-10 in the first section, and 11-20 in the next section, and there doesn't seem to be a good way to do that.
In the end, I think I'm better off just using a component on each field, like so:

```
{{attribute-component value=model.attr1}}
{{attribute-component value=model.attr2}}
.
.
.
```

Comment: Even if I have to call the component multiple times, I found that it wasn't very laborious (using Excel functions to generate the repeating code). I just have a line like this for each field: `{{button-radios value=model.art title='ART'}}`

Comment: Yes you can use component for each field. [found that it wasn't very laborious (using Excel functions to generate the repeating code]. this wont be a problem.

Comment: @prudviraju: if you know how, could you submit an answer with some sample code please?

Comment: can you post your sample what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a neat helper called `each-in` that iterates over key/attributes of an object.

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/templates/displaying-the-keys-in-an-object/

There is a way to do that in your case, but I think that actually a simpler way to get the same effect is this:

---

```
template.hbs

{{#each myArrayOfPeople as | person | }}
    {{#each attribs as | anAttrib | }}
      {{get person (mut anAttrib)}},
    {{/each}}
    <br>
{{/each}}
```

---

```
component.js

attribKeys:['name', 'phoneNumber', 'otherAttrib'];
```

This will output something like:

```
joe, 123, something,
sam, 456, anotherthing,
sarah, 944, foo
```

you can use that same `(mut anAttrib)` helper to bind an attribute to an input or whatever your need is.

`{{attribute-component value=(mut anAttrib)}}`

Comment: In terms of various sections, you would just set up multiple arrays of attributes, one for each section. `sectionOneAttribs`, `sectionTwoAttribs` etc

Comment: I wish so badly I could use 'mut' but I'm on 1.11 still, and now I'm trying to figure out how to change a model field that's changed in a nested component.

Comment: oof. I'd upgrade first off :) "change a model field that's changed in a nested component" sounds like you need some quality Data Down Actions Up here...

Comment: agreed. I just can't for the life of me figure it out. There's only about a dozen other questions on it, but none of them make sense to me. I think I have something that should work, but the innermost component is ember-radio-button, and that's what's giving me problems, complaining that I have no action handler assigned, when I do. Actions are the bane of my existence with Ember, and I just wish I could fully grok it instead of going through this same trial-and-error every time I have a component.

Comment: Whatever is the container for the radio button, you just need an action defined in `actions:{ onChange }`, and set `changed='onChange'. Pass in the parent `{{parent-component onChange="onChange"}}` then in the `parent-component` call `sendAction("onChange", newValue)`

Comment: But really, upgrade. It is punishing to be in old versions of Ember. Particularly < 1.13

Comment: I know. I actually have started to try, but the app was immediately broken and the errors too cryptic to figure out (for me at least). I've gotta convince management to hire outside help to get over that hump.

Comment: If you can bump up to 1.13 that would be a big deal. You'll end up with deprecation warnings, but nothing got removed until 2.0...

Comment: I'm trying now thanks to your encouragement. But it looks like I have a lot of work to do figuring out cryptic error messages like 'cannot read property '0' of undefined' before my app is even back to a working state, regardless of all the deprecation warnings. Sigh....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114894/discussion-between-averydev-and-redoctober13).

Answer (score 0):

I have now forgone trying to iterate over each field because I actually need to break out the fields into accordion containers based on other criteria, although @averydev's answer about nested `{{#each}}` was a very cool tip and useful.

I also updated to Ember 1.13 in order to use the `mut` helper (although I had previously used an action on the component, that passes the new value to an action in the controller, that sets the value to the model property. Since that was convoluted, this new method using `mut` is much more understandable.

Just to help anyone else out in the future, here's my code (simplified for SO, the real code has nothing to do with rooms and furniture). I have a custom component that uses a radio button group component to actually set the value (this is from [ember-radio-button](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-radio-button)):

**template.hbs**

```
{{room-style title='Living Room' field=(mut model.livingRoomStyle)}}
{{room-style title='Master Bedroom' field=(mut model.masterStyle)}}
```

**templates/components/room-style.hbs**

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  {{#radio-button value=1 groupValue=field classNames="btn btn-default" changed="changed"}}
    Modern
  {{/radio-button}}
  {{#radio-button value=2 groupValue=field classNames="btn btn-default" changed="changed"}}
    French
  {{/radio-button}}
  {{#radio-button value=3 groupValue=field classNames="btn btn-default" changed="changed"}}
    Rustic
  {{/radio-button}}
</div>
```

**components/room-style.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    changed: function() {
      //update() is a function you get with attrs.[prop] when using the mut helper
      this.attrs.field.update(this.get('field'));
    }
  }
});
```